# Google crawl speed -- how fast can it go?

Tags: google, search-engine-indexing, web-crawlers

I have a huge website with 5 million pages. Currently Google indexes about 10,000 pages per day. This is very slow, I still have lots of pages that I can't get indexed. Does anyone know what is the upper threshold for crawl speed?

Comment: In general, 5 million quality pages don't just suddenly appear on the web. Have they been moved from somewhere? If they are low quality pages, Google will not be interested in crawling and indexing.

Comment: When you say that 10,000 pages per day are "indexed" how do you know?  Is this the number that is crawled, or is this how much the number of indexed pages is increasing in webmaster tools each day?

Comment: It is shown in the crawl graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out that it is possible to achieve 2 pages/second crawl speed by improving server responce time. Each page should responce as fast as possible. This may require garbage collector tuning, db tuning and code tuning. If average responce time is better then 50ms per second, then google would index at 2pages/sec, this is experimental fact.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum speed of indexing is 10 times per second. This is the speed of StackOverflow indexing by Google (read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/eeeeek-where-is-my-slow-performance/84701#84701)).

Comment: That isn't an absolute upper bound.  Just what is available to a site with stackoverflow's pagerank.  I've worked with higher PR sites that have higher crawl rates available.

Answer (score 2):

Google's crawl rate is a function of:

- Pagerank -- the more reputation and inbound links your site has, the more it will be crawled.  Within your site the most prominent pages (like the home page) will get crawled more often because they have higher pagerank.
- How often your pages change -- pages that change frequently will get re-crawled more often that pages that don't.
- How fast your server is -- rather than having a number of pages per day that Googlebot downloads, it appears that it is limited by the amount of time spent downloading pages.   Making pages smaller and increasing the speed of the server can both let Googlebot crawl faster.

In addition, Googlebot has several different crawl modes.

- Re-crawl mode -- it will come back and visit pages that it has visited before.
- Fresh crawl mode -- it will crawl lots of new pages in a new section of a site.  The higher the pagerank of the site, the more pages get crawled.
- Stale pages mode -- Googlebot finds a box of old links in the basement and plows through them just for "fun".  These pages are often all pages that no longer exist and are redirected to other pages.  They often have no pagerank and are crawled in URL-length order.

The upshot of this is that the best way to get your site crawled faster is to get inbound links and increase the pagerank.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the mentioned above is true, although an important remark - scanned and indexed are not the same. So when you think it's 10,000 links per day, in fact it's a big question how many of them did it really manage to open.

Google and Yandex determine the speed based on the value of the website as they see it, but till a certain extent you can interfere in it manually.

There might be though a workaround* to get out of this cycle:

1. Try changing the [GSC Crawl rate settings](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/settings) - it may rescan your website much faster
2. If you're using a dynamic sitemap.xml file, you may try:

2.1. Adding all the sub-sitemap files directly into the Sitemap section in Google Search Console
2.2. Adding all the sub-sitemap files directly into the robots.txt file, so the search engine will read them not only via the index file but will get referred via robots file (might be quite efficient)

*An important issue to mention about the crawl speed - if your speed settings will be too fast for what in practice your server can handle, a result of this change will be many 4xx/5xx responses, which will disappoint Google even more or just not help much (Google will start saving crawling budget on your website).

So make sure you set the right speed to avoid empty calls - this way you can indeed rescan your website much faster than it normally happens.

Answer (score 1):

If they're crawling your pages and they're not being found in the search results then the crawl rate is not an issue. This sounds like your website is full of low quality content that Google does *not* want in its index. Is this original content? Is it quality content? Google not listing your pages indicates that it is not.